# Is a substring of a CSPRN also a CSPRN?

Tags: c#, string, random, cryptography

I want to generate a 4 character long CSPRN (Cryptographically Secure Psuedo Random Number) string. I know I can create an 8 character one by creating a 5 byte long random array and encoding as base32:

```
string CSPRN = "";
System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] tokenData = new byte[5];
rng.GetBytes(tokenData);
CSPRN = Base32.ToBase32String(tokenData);  //should produce a string 5bytes*1.6charsperbyte = 8 chars long.
```

If I now take a substring of the first 4 characters of CSPRN - is it still a CSPRN?

My best guess is that it is, but wondering if there is any "gotcha"s from taking a substring rather than generating a smaller number.

Comment: Funny enough, I am doing that Coursera class online, the one taught by Dan Boneh (I recommend it highly), and they covered this topic among others.  Yes, any portion of the output of a CSPRN is cryptographically secure.  Even down to the individual bit being indistinguishable in randomness from a coin toss.  If it were not secure even at that level, it would be impossible to construct a cryptographically secure larger output from that system.  Consider also that many stream ciphers rely on this very property, random even at the bit level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. First lets look at your first security claim. Base 32 is a 5 bit encoding, so if you generate 5 times anything, say a byte, the string you generate contains full entropy per character.

Now the amount of entropy per character doesn't suddenly drop if you take it out of the string of course. So if you take 4 characters each should still contain the full entropy, giving you simply 4 characters of full of entropy *within the base 32 alphabet*.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer - yes, entropy per character is the same for all substrings - but that in itself doesn't really prove anything

Comment: Each character simply represents 5 bits out of the RNG. As long as this is the case you basically don't have to worry. Is that a better description? You can also ask at the crypto site to have an experts opinion, although I'm in the top 10 there as well :P